# Fold show first line of docstring, keeps other folds intact

Tags: vimrc, gvim

Following this [article](https://chrisdown.name/2015/02/26/folding-python-docstrings-in-vim.html), fold show first line `set foldtext=getline(v:foldstart+1)`, it does but other folds in file look bad, see pics:

When set `foldtext=getline(v:foldstart+1)`
[image]

Without set `foldtext=getline(v:foldstart+1)`:
[image]

So I'd like to have function/class folded as 2rd pic, and docstring folded as 1st pic. I used `SimpylFold` plugin for auto-fold in python.

EDIT 1: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18241768/5813693), I wonder if I only need to match docstring and fold it: `substitute(a:string, '^[[:space:][:return:][:cntrl:]]\+\|[[:space:][:return:][:cntrl:]]\+$', '', '')`

Comment: Adding the required docstring to the function would be to simple?

Comment: Coud you give more specific?. In `python.vim`, can/how we add `set foldtext=getline(v:foldstart+1)` to `pythonString` region?

Comment: You are displaying the doc string for the folded regions. Apparently, some lines to be folded to not contain doc strings. So I suggest to simply add the doc strings to those folds that miss them. Apart from that I am missing information here, e.g. what are you folding related settings?

Comment: `SimpylFold` plugin auto-fold func/class/docstring for me, this is fold options in my vimrc: `set foldclose= foldcolumn=0 foldenable foldlevel=0 foldmarker& foldmethod=manual`. I haven't touched python.vim for fold yet. So no fold setting in python.vim.

Comment: since this is a plugin problem, consider ask at the plugin page.

Comment: Even if without plugin how we can make docstring fold/unfold on demand?